How to get the classnames by node-tree-sitter?
I want to get all classNames, I think as long as I match all the class node, I could get the classname,
so I tried below code:
const Parser = require("tree-sitter")
const JavaScript = require("tree-sitter-javascript")
const { Query } = Parser 


const parser = new Parser()
parser.setLanguage(JavaScript)

const query = new Query(
  JavaScript,
  `
    (class_declaration name: (identifier) @class-name)
  `
);


const tree = parser.parse(`
class Person {}
 
const TestPerson = class {}

class Person2 {}
 
const TestPerson2 = class {}
  `);
const matches = query.matches(tree.rootNode);

matches.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item.captures[0])
})


When I execute it:
$ node query-test.js 
{
  name: 'class-name',
  node: IdentifierNode {
    type: identifier,
    startPosition: {row: 2, column: 6},
    endPosition: {row: 2, column: 12},
    childCount: 0,
  }
}
{
  name: 'class-name',
  node: IdentifierNode {
    type: identifier,
    startPosition: {row: 8, column: 6},
    endPosition: {row: 8, column: 13},
    childCount: 0,
  }
}

there is no classname ['Person', 'Person2'],
please tell me how to get the class names.

item.captures[0].node.text - there stores class names

@MehriddinNozimov  great, this works.
